# Installing my own package generates a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<my package>' when installed via pypi

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py, pypi

## The context

I am creating my first package named `countries_utils`, made available on https://pypi.org/project/countries-utils.

I have read the following tutorials:

1. Packaging Python Projects
   https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/
2. Managing Application Dependencies https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/#managing-dependencies
3. Packaging and distributing projects https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#distributing-packages

## The code of the library `countries_utils`

The source code of the library is available on bitbucket :

- https://bitbucket.org/altf1be/countries-utils/src/master/

### The issue

1. I run the command `pip install countries-utils`
2. I download the latest version of the library
3. I run the `python` command
4. I import the library using `import countries_utils`
5. I get the error : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'countries_utils'`

**QUESTION : What am I missing?**

## Result of the `pip list` command

```
pip list

Package                                       Version    
--------------------------------------------- -----------
...
contextlib2                                   0.5.5
countries-utils                               1.0.13
country-list                                  0.1.4
cryptography                                  2.7
...
```

## Error

This is the result of doing `import countries_utils` in the python console:

```
> python

Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import countries_utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'countries_utils'
```

## setup.py file (WORKING VERSION)

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Copyright (c) ALT-F1 SPRL, Abdelkrim Boujraf. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the EUPL License, Version 1.2.
# See LICENSE in the project root for license information.

from os import path
import json
import setuptools

with open('README.md', 'r') as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()


here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
root = path.dirname(here)
package_json = path.join(here, 'package.json')
# a workaround when installing locally from git repository with pip install -e .

if not path.isfile(package_json):
    package_json = path.join(root, 'package.json')

# version number and all other params from package.json
with open(package_json, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    package = json.load(f)

setuptools.setup(
    name=package['name'],
    version=package['version'],
    author=package['author']['name'],
    author_email=package['author']['email'],
    description=package['description'],
    license=package['license'],
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url=package['repository']['url'],
    install_requires=[
        'pycountry',
        'pandas',
        'country-list'
    ],
    packages=[package['name']],
    keywords=package['keywords'],

    # Find the list of classifiers : https://pypi.org/classifiers/
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: European Union Public Licence 1.2 (EUPL 1.2)',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    ],

    python_requires='>=3.5',

    project_urls={  # Optional
        'Bug Reports': 'https://bitbucket.org/altf1be/countries-utils/issues?status=new&status=open',
        'Company behind the library': 'http://www.alt-f1.be',
        'Source': 'https://bitbucket.org/altf1be/countries-utils',
    },

)
```

Comment: You need to post your `setup.py` here, not a link to an external repo, so that people viewing this question would see the same set of codes to reproduce the problem. The codes in Bitbucket (especially links to the master branch) can change or disappear over time.

Comment: A quick check after installing your package from PyPi ( `pip install countries_utils`) shows that no `countries_utils` folder gets added to the `site-packages` directory, so.. the error is expected.

Comment: dear @gino-mempin what is missing to create the folder site-packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's this:

```
packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
...
package_dir={'': 'countries_utils'},  # Optional
```

From Python's [Distutils Examples](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/examples.html) (emphasis mine):

> If you want to put modules in directories **not named for their package**,
>   then you need to use the `package_dir` option again. For example, if the
>   `src` directory holds modules in the `foobar` package:
>
> ```
> <root>/
>         setup.py
>         src/
>                  __init__.py
>                  foo.py
>                  bar.py
> ```
>
> an appropriate setup script would be
>
> ```
> from distutils.core import setup
> setup(name='foobar',
>       version='1.0',
>       package_dir={'foobar': 'src'},
>       packages=['foobar'],
>       )
> ```

In your case, the package name is `countries_utils`, and you already have an appropriately named package directory `countries_utils`. So there is no need for the `package_dir` option. It's only used when the packages to install are in a folder of a different name.

Comment: I managed to make it work based on your feedback and the Distutils examples link